# tsc --build outputs same error multiple times

Tags: typescript, monorepo

I have the following project structure:

```
my-monorepo
├── tsconfig.json
└── packages
    ├── package-one
    │   └── index.ts: import packageThree from '@my-monorepo/package-three'
    ├── package-two
    │   └── index.ts: import packageThree from '@my-monorepo/package-three'
    └── package-three
        └── index.ts: // have some ts error
```

In that case `tsb -b` report error in pacakge-three pacakge **x3** times.
The following settings do not help:

```
"skipLibCheck": true,
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

How do I get the typscript to scan only src files without delving into the dependencies?